# Como criar um gráfico sendo que os valores apresentados nele estará no BD

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho um tabela no meu BD que registra um histórico de progressão dos usuários.

Essa tabela é composta pelos campos `ID / ID_USER / NOTA / DATA`.
Todo dia meia noite esses valores são recalculados.

Supondo então que no dia 09/02/2015 o usuário tinha uma nota de 380 e no final do dia ele chegou a uma nota de 400, o script que eu fiz vai recalcular a nota de todos os ID e fará a inserção na tabela com os novos dados, porem não excluindo os antigos.

Eis então o que eu quero fazer.
Quero montar um gráfico, quero que esse gráfico exiba os últimos 30 resultados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho preferencia por PHP, mas qualquer linguagem será bem vinda, desde que isso seja possível! Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Sim e possivel, amanha dou uma resposta mais detalhada de como faco isso, por hora deixo pra vc dar uma lida a seguinte documentacao: http://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: Ivan, achei sua pergunta muito ampla... O que você tentou até aqui? Qual a dificuldade específica? Como montar o gráfico? Inserir a nota?

Comment: Você esta pedindo que façamos o serviço por você. Por favor, leia http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para entender como devem ser feitas perguntas.

Comment: @gmsantos a dificuldade em questão é como montar o grafico

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom, assumo pra essa resposta que o que você quer descobrir é **somente** como utilizar `PHP` + uma `API` que desenhe gráficos, e você já criou todo a dinâmica de gravação e recuperação de dados do `BD`.

Primeiramente eu recomendo fortemente a leitura da documentação da `API jquery` [`HighCharts`](http://www.highcharts.com/), o link também é a fonte original de algumas informações que irei passar aqui.

Na montagem do gráfico eu trabalho com um arquivo `PHP`¹, montando todas as consultas e retornando todos os dados que eu quero exibir na tela em campos `<input type="hidden">`

Agora basta trabalhar com o `JQuery`. A função é personalizável e você monta o tipo de gráfico que você quiser

**Explicando a API HighCharts**

> Highcharts is solely based on native browser technologies and doesn't
>   require client side plugins like Flash or Java. Furthermore you don't
>   need to install anything on your server. No PHP or ASP.NET. Highcharts
>   needs only two JS files to run: The highcharts.js core and either the
>   jQuery, MooTools, Prototype or Highcharts Standalone framework. The
>   Highcharts Standalone framework is designed for those who do not
>   already use jQuery, MooTools or Prototype in their web page, and wish
>   to use Highcharts with minimal overhead.
>
> Highcharts and Highstock work in all modern browsers including mobile
>   devices and Internet Explorer from version 6. Standard browsers use
>   SVG for the graphics rendering. In legacy Internet Explorer (IE8 and
>   before) graphics are drawn using VML.

Traduzido e interpretado do original:

> Highcharts é baseada em tecnologias do navegador nativo e
>   não necessita de plugins do lado do cliente, como Flash ou Java. Além
>   disso, você não precisa instalar nada no seu servidor. No PHP ou
>   ASP.NET. Highcharts precisa de apenas dois arquivos JS para executar:
>   O núcleo highcharts.js e, ou o framework jQuery, MooTools, Prototype
>   ou Highcharts Standalone. O quadro Highcharts Standalone é projetado
>   para aqueles que ainda não usam jQuery, MooTools ou Prototype em sua
>   página web, e deseja usar Highcharts com sobrecarga mínima.
>
> Highcharts e Highstock  trabalham em todos os browsers modernos,
>   inclusive serviços mobile e versão IE6. Por padrão utiliza-se a
>   tecnologia SVG para renderizar os gráficos. No lendário IE8 e
>   anteriores, o gráfico é desenhado utilizando a tecnologia VML.

**Browsers que suportam o `HighCharts`:**

[image: aqui]

**Framework que trabalham com o `HighCharts`:**

[image: aqui]

**OBS1**: A consulta e retorno dos dados também pode ser feito com `AJAX`, na verdade até poderia simplificar o trabalho, mas ai fica a seu encargo

**OBS2**: Necessário a utilização das libs:

```
 - jquery.js;
 - highcharts.js;
 - exporting.js;
```

**Exemplo da utilização:**

```js
$(function () {
    nota = new Array;
    for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
  nota[x] = parseInt(document.getElementById("nota"+x).value);
 }
    
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: '10 Últimas alterações'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Aluno'
        },
        xAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value;
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Notas'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value;
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: 'Nota do {series.name} <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                pointStart: 0,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Aluno X',
            data: [nota[1], nota[2], nota[3], nota[4], nota[5], nota[6], nota[7], nota[8], nota[9], nota[10]]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <input type="hidden" id="nota1" name="nota1" value="5">
    <input type="hidden" id="nota2" name="nota2" value="10">
    <input type="hidden" id="nota3" name="nota3" value="10">
    <input type="hidden" id="nota4" name="nota4" value="8">
    <input type="hidden" id="nota5" name="nota5" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" id="nota6" name="nota6" value="3">
    <input type="hidden" id="nota7" name="nota7" value="7">
    <input type="hidden" id="nota8" name="nota8" value="9">
    <input type="hidden" id="nota9" name="nota9" value="8">
    <input type="hidden" id="nota10" name="nota10" value="3">

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```